# Baikal needs write permission in the Specific folder

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, xampp

I am trying to set up a test iCloud Calendar API thing, so I am trying to set it up using XAMPP on my Linux computer.  After reading many forums on how to do it, I found that Baikal is the easiest way to use CalDAV.  I first tried to use their `Regular Package`, and followed the instructions, but I keep getting the error message:

```
Error - Insufficient permissions on the Specific/ folder

In order to work properly, Baïkal needs to have write permissions in the Specific/ folder.
```

No matter how many times I do `chown -R [username] Directory/to/Specific` and check to make sure it worked by using `ls -l Directory/to/Specific`, it still gives the same error.  I ended up giving up with the `Regular Package` and tried their `Flat Package` thinking it would be easier/faster since the description of the package states:

> Download this package if you want Baïkal up and running quickly

I followed the Instructions *again*, and it still gave the same exact error as above.

Am I missing something, or is this an issue with XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

The folder Baikal has to be assigned to www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data baikal/ 
sudo find baikal/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue at Fedora 28. The culprit was SELinux, after disabling it (setenforce 0) the page came OK.